# Table namespace error in vs2010/c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I added a table in my project which is along these lines:

```
            Table table1 = new Table();
            table1.RowGroups.Add(new TableRowGroup());
            table1.RowGroups[1].Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            TableRow currentRow = table1.RowGroups[1].Rows[1];
```

When I added the table, to reference it, i added a reference presentationFramework.dll to start using the namespace "System.Windows.Documents". Then it started giving me 3 errors

> The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>
> The type 'System.Windows.IInputElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>
> The type 'System.Windows.ContentElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I don't understand this. What should I do to correct this error?

Please help me

Comment: You have ASP.NET as a tag, but isn't this a WPF/Silverlight question?

Comment: changed the title and the tags accordingly !! Thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a reference to PresentationCore DLL, which is also in the GAC and is required.

Brian

Comment: Then i started to get this error  
The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. What should I do?

Comment: OK, your post mentions PresentationFramework, not PresentationCore.  Is this a WPF/Silverlight project?  You could try dropping the references and re-adding them... is this a silverlight project?  Did you setup a silverlight app?

Comment: no it is a asp.net web application project. Can't I add a table in asp.net web application project ? Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm new to this environment. All I know is asp.net web application project and console aplication using c#

Comment: OK, so you must mean silverlight.  You have to create a special silverlight project template, make sure you download the Silverlight SDK.  No you can't drop these objects into an ASP.NET project, you create a silverlight project with these screens and drop them into the ASP.NET project.  Using the silverlight template, it will create the correct applications for you (it creates the ASP.NET web application too and embeds the silverlight viewer).